# How to work with Versionable entities with Doctrine2 Extensions?

Tags: php, version, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use [Versionable](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/) extension from Doctrine2Extensions but I couldn't a way to implement it.

It is mentioned that we need to 'implements' Versionable interface (which is empty by the way)

> Requirements of your entities are:
>
> Single Identifier Column (String or
> Integer)
>
> Entity has to be versioned
> (using @version annotation)
>
> Implementing Versionable would look
> like:

```
namespace MyProject;
use DoctrineExtensions\Versionable\Versionable;

class BlogPost implements Versionable {
    // blog post API 
}
```

From the documentation.

What I don't understand is :

Single Identifier Column (String or Integer)
Entity has to be versioned (using @version annotation)

What those both requirements means?

Here my entity:

```
<?php
namespace Jo\Model;
use DoctrineExtensions\Versionable\Versionable;
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Comment implements Versionable
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $body;
```

What are missing to make version works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $id property provides a single identifier.

From my reading of things, you'll also need a $version (or similar) property, which could be an integer or datetime, and it must be annoted with [@Version](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-version)

This (old) [blog post](https://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/02/24/doctrine2-versionable.html) may help give you some more insight (but some of it may be out of date)

Comment: link dead, see http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-behaviours-nutshell.html#versionable